# Regex to extract info from SQL query

Tags: sql, regex, text-extraction

As I am new for the REGEX i am not able to solve below thing.

And please share some parser related links so the i can learn it.

I am facing problem in solving int below SQL statement.
Its more line added to the previous INPUT.

Please help me to slove this.

```
DECLARE
numerator   NUMBER;
BEGIN
SELECT x, y INTO numerator, denominator FROM result_table, s_Table
WHERE sample_id = 8;
the_ratio := numerator/denominator;
IF the_ratio > lower_limit THEN
INSERT INTO 
ratio VALUES (table, coloum);
ELSE
INSERT INTO onemoreTable VALUES (table, -1);
END IF;
COMMIT;
delete from     --some comment
xyz where id=17;
EXCEPTION
WHEN ZERO_DIVIDE THEN
INSERT INTO ratio VALUES (table, 0);
COMMIT;
WHEN OTHERS THEN
ROLLBACK;
END;
```

OUTPUT:

```
SELECT from: result_table, s_Table
INSERT into: ratio
INSERT into: onemoreTable
DELETE from: xyz
INSERT into: ratio
```

Comment: Sneaky, with the comment there. For real SQL there are more complex scenarios, and you probably want an SQL parser. What language is this, anyway?

Comment: I agree with Kobi, unless you can guarantee very basic queries you probably are best to get a proper SQL parser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a Perl based solution using regex:

```
$input =~s/--.*?\n//g; # delete the comments.
$input =~s/\s+/ /g; # replace multiple white space with single space.
while($input=~m/((?:insert into)|(?:delete from)) (\w+)/ig) { 
        print "$1 : $2\n";    
}
```

The right way to parse SQL is to do it using a parser and not using regex.